# Can a person apply for a patent - and not let other contributors know he is applying?

Tags: invalidation, inequitable-conduct

We have a situation where 3 people worked on an idea. We suspect that one of the people may have applied for a patent without informing or acknowledging the contributions of the others.

I am a newbie at the patent process.

How would the other two contributors determine whether this has been done?

Answer (score 3):

- You can watch for the application to be published, but that could take a while.
- You could inform the person in question that not listing all inventors will essentially       invalidate the application
- "Worked on an idea" will need some clarification.  Did all the parties participate with meaningful conceptual input?

Comment: The problem here is that one of the contributors is wealthier , can afford expensive lawyers and has a convenient memory.  Once a  patent is granted, it can be expensive legally for the other contributors to appeal - which is probably part of the strategy. So apart from a "please do not do this" letter to him, is there any action the other contributors can take to prevent this person from walking away with the sole rights to a possible patent.  Is there some way to notify the USPTO - so the examiner will at least contact the others during application review ?

Comment: Sounds like you guys are telling the OP that he is in a bad way?

Answer (score 3):

The 'invention' is defined by the patent claims.   Joint inventorship also is a claim by claim analysis.  In other words, dick and jane invent AB, but jane only invented B, so dick can claim only A and is not required to include jane as inventor, but if a claim to AB is made then dick and jane both must be named as inventors.